# Android HttpUrlConnection does POST instead of GET

Tags: android, http, post, get, httpurlconnection

I've got an Android app that's trying to do a GET request to my server using HttpUrlConnection. When I test the code in a separate testing desktop application, everything works fine. However, when I run it on my android device, my server registers a POST request instead of a GET.

Here's the code for my `get` method:

```
public static String get(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = connFromUrlString(url);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.connect();

    String out = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    conn.disconnect();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Note: it seems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036232/post-requests-received-as-get-with-android-httpurlconnection) might be a similar question, so if anybody has an answer, they may want to go post it there or poke the [author](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1596293/yotam) (I will too when I see an answer).

Comment: conn.setDoOutput(true); not needed with GET method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This line is the culprit.

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Remove that and give it a try.

By the way, you should read this excellent piece: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/415412

Comment: Also thanks to @Niko, who originally suggested this.

Comment: Answer is correct, link to other SO post is helpful - all OK. But @joshlf13, you could consider using a library like [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/) to get a more convenient way to access webservers (especially from Android devices). There you can find links to other powerful libraries like Volley.

Comment: OK, thanks. Those look interesting; I'll check them out!